# gcloud logging read command returns nothing

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, gcloud, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am trying to pull all old logs for BigQuery for a project, so I can add them to my logs dataset that I have set up via sink.  I have tried both:

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=bigquery_resource AND \
  logName=projects/ql2infare/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access"
```

and

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=bigquery_resource AND logName=projects/ql2infare/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access"
```

Both seem to process, but then I don't get anything returned, even though I have logs for the last day for that project.  I will need to run this for the last Q once I have this working for 1 day. I can't seem to find any info in the GCP documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the freshness flag when retrieving logs more than 1 day old.

gcloud logging read [LOG_FILTER] [--freshness=FRESHNESS; default="1d"]

See details [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read)

Answer (score 3):

Guoest has a good point about freshness, but there's another issue that can make this happen: if your gcloud default project is not set to the project whose logs you are trying to access, you need to add the `--project` flag. In your example, this would look like:

```
gcloud logging read "resource.type=bigquery_resource AND \
  logName=projects/ql2infare/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access" \
  --project=ql2infare
```

Otherwise, it tries to look for logs in whatever project is set set to the default, which will not turn up any logs for `ql2infare` if it's a different project. Alternatively, you could do `gcloud config set project ql2infare` to change that default before running the logs query. For more info, see the docs for [`gcloud logging read`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read) and [`gcloud config set`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set).

Comment: Adding the project flag worked for me

Answer (score -1):

you have to log in as the user who has access to the underlying resource you are trying to get the logs for, using gcloud auth login, then run the command.